# Java generic class as a parameter

Tags: java, generics

I'm dealing with a legacy project. There is a generic object DataWrapper (simplified in this illustration) with parameterized type. Normally I can used it like so: `DataWrapper<Integer> d = new DataWrapper<Integer>();` or `DataWrapper<MyObjectX> d = new DataWrapper<MyObjectX>();`

```
class DataWrapper <T> {
  protected List<T> data;
  public List<T> getData() {
    return data;
  }
  public void setData(List<T> data) {
    this.data = data;
  } 
}
```

But then this object need to be transmitted through a web service in my case I'm using `org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponse`.

```
ClientResponse clientResponse = (ClientResponse) myRestObject.myRestMethod();

// Then convert it back to DataWrapper<MyObjectX>
// This is where the issue happened, I think!
DataWrapper<MyObjectX> result = clientResponse.getEntity(DataWrapper.class);
```

In the statement above **I cannot pass MyObjectX** like the following `DataWrapper<MyObjectX> result = clientResponse.getEntity(DataWrapper<MyObjectX>.class);`

I can call `List<MyObjectX> myList = result.getData();` 
But when iterating it will become an error

```
for (MyObjectX o: myList) {
  // ERROR!
  // java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap 
  // cannot be cast to class com.mypackage.MyObjectX
  logger.info(o.getName());
}
```

```
package org.jboss.resteasy.client;
public abstract class ClientResponse<T> extends Response{
   public abstract <T2> T2 getEntity(Class<T2> type);
}
```

So my question is: how do we pass a generic class as the type? Or is this not possible?

Comment: You may have to get the string entity and map manually (like with jackson's `mapper.readValue(clientResponse.getEntity(String.class), new TypeReference<DataWrapper<MyObjectX>>(){})`

Comment: What is the type of `ClientResponse`?  What libraries are you using, etc.?

Comment: Hi @ernest_k I think your answer is working. You just need to add.
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Could you please add your comment as the "Answer" section?
Also how were you able to determine that it can be done using Jackson's mapper? com.fasterxml.jackson.core

Comment: You can make a `MyObjectXDataWrapper implements DataWrapper<MyObjectX>` class and then do `clientResponse.getEntity(MyObjectXDataWrapper.class);`